# Is there a built-in function like Perl's splice in Python?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to find a way to find/replace elements from list other than using iteration like there is a function splice() in perl.

```
@a = splice(@list,2,3,(1,1,1));
print @a;
```

In python we need to go through loop and find and the replace. This is looking bit time consuming. So is there any way to replace like we do in Perl?

Answer (score 10):

You can use slice assignment:

```
somelist[2:5] = [1, 1, 1]
```

This takes the elements 2, 3 and 4, replacing them with the new list. The new list doesn't have to be the same length, or can be empty. The slice you assign to can be of length 0 too, effectively inserting the right-hand sequence into the target list.

Demo:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a[1:1] = [4, 5, 6]
>>> a
[1, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3]
>>> b = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'spam', 'ham', 'eggs']
>>> b[2:5] = [1, 1, 1]
>>> b
['foo', 'bar', 1, 1, 1, 'eggs']
>>> c = [42, 38, 22]
>>> c[:2] = []
>>> c
[22]
```

Slice assignment covers all the same use cases the [Perl `splice()` function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html) supports.

Comment: Any way of inserting the right hand list into the left hand one without removing any elements from the left hand one?

Comment: @Hubro: sure, just pick two indices *between* the elements; `somelist[1:1] = iterable` would insert after `somelist[1]`, before `somelist[2]`.

Comment: @Hubro: I do cover this in my answer: *The slice you assign to can be of length 0 too* and the demo covers this explicitly.

Comment: Right, I should have read the answer more carefully... I kind of assumed that it couldn't be done in this way. Didn't know you could reference a position between two indexes using `[]`.